# LyX: Unable to open file with hebrew characters in the path

Tags: lyx, hebrew

I am using LyX version 2.3.7 on my Windows 10 machine and for some reason, can't open LyX files with hebrew characters in the path (not in the content and not in the filename itself, just in one of the directories that include them). The files do open when I move them to another path. So `D:\Path\אל\file.lyx` won't open but `D:\Path\to\file.lyx` will.

When I say 'can't open' I mean an error window with the text `Unable to open file D:\...` pops up. I can't save files in these paths, either. I've tried to look up this problem online but I only found problems related to hebrew in the content of the document itself or in the LaTeX, I'm assuming my problem is related to the workings of LyX itself, not the LaTeX engine (I'm using MikTeX if that's relevant).

The thing is, I know for a fact it DID work in some previous version of LyX on another machine (that's where I created these files and directories in the first place a few years ago) so I might've messed up while I installed LyX but I'm not sure how. Of course I can just change the names of the directories on my computer but that's a very annoying solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a lyx problem so you should report it there. Beside this you could try to upgrade to windows 11, its handling of non-ascii file names seems to be better (but I wouldn't bet that there aren't still applications and older hard drives where it fails).

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The solution was to change the active Windows code page to be Unicode ([here's](https://robocorp.com/docs/troubleshooting/windows-codepage) a guide). I don't know enough about codepages to know if this was LyX's fault for not manually using Unicode and trusting the active codepage or my fault for not configuring my machine correctly but the bottom line is this works.

Comment: can you raise this topic in LyX's developers mailing list? maybe a better error message can be made or something: http://lists.lyx.org/mailman/listinfo/lyx-devel

Comment: I will, good idea!

Comment: Great,, thanks!